# Create multiple text files with distinct names from dictionary keys

Tags: python

I'm trying to create multiple text files from each key in a dictionary.

I have made several unsuccessful attempts. The result is that the files are produced correctly, but only the last key (Signal 8) is being written to every file. I don't know where I'm messing up.

```
signals_dict = {'Signal 1': 1, 
                'Signal 2': 1, 
                'Signal 3': 1, 
                'Signal 4': 1, 
                'Signal 5': 1, 
                'Signal 6': 1, 
                'Signal 7': 1, 
                'Signal 8': 1}


def to_string():
    count = 0
    while count <= len(signals_dict):
        count +=1
        for keys,values in signals_dict.items():
            with open(f'signal{count}.txt','w') as wf:
                wf.write(keys)

to_string()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop *and* a `while` loop. Use only a `for` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not very clear what you want to do here. 
If you want to properly iterate over the dictionary, try doing `for key, item in dictionary.items()` and if you want to also get an index you could try `enumerate` wrapper

Comment: Hey @Tomerikoo, thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion, and it worked. However, the problem now is that only the last key is being written to all of the files. I've updated my question if you'd like to take look.

Comment: Hey @mkrieger1,  thanks for your suggestion, but how else can use increment if not with a while loop? The files need to be named signal1, signal2, etc., hence why I opted for a while loop. As for the for loop, that is to iterate over the dict. Would you mind showing me how you would do?

Comment: Hey @UpmostScarab, thanks for taking the time to explain. I think my for loop in and of itself works properly, but what's not working is that only the last key (Signal 8) is being written to all of the files. I've updated my question and code if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just after a unique file name (based on the key) that contains the value?  If so:

```
for name, value in signals_dict.items():
  with open(f"{name}.txt", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(str(value))
```

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis on the end of your `open()` statement.

Comment: @CUI I just tested g.d.d.c's code, it does exactly what you asked for in your original post. Can you clarify why you think their code is not doing what you want?

Comment: Hey @blackbrandt, yes his code works perfectly. The problem is that the keys in the actual files (not the sample I provided) are dozens of characters long. Instead, I'd like to name the files as "signal1.txt, signal2,txt, etc.

Comment: So you want 8 files: Signal1.txt, Signal2.txt ... Signal8.txt. Each file should contain its corresponding value from the dictionary, right?

Comment: I've updated this to use `enumerate` so you get indices of the loop as well when you pass through it.

Comment: @g.d.d.c this would break if the actual insertion order of the key: value pairs was not in the numeric order required by OP, and it would break in a really bad way that wouldn't be immediately apparent.

Comment: Yeah, but it sounds like their keys aren't actually `Signal 1`. In any event, reverted to Rev2.